# Using Notepad++ as IE7 "View Source" Application

Tags: internet-explorer, notepad++, internet-explorer-7

The method described at the end of [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906105525/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2007/03/28/ie7-in-vista-configuring-your-view-source-editor.aspx) blog entry has instructions for making Notepad++ (or any application) the default text editor for IE7's View Source feature. The problem is, the file IE7 sends to Notepad++ has no extension (in particular, does not have an .html extension) and therefore is displayed as plain text in Notepad++. Is there anyway to tell Notepad++ to use HTML as the Language in this scenario? Perhaps the registry value can be modified to pass an argument to notepad++.exe indicating the language to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Preferences > New document` set the default language to HTML. This work either for new files and files without extension.

Comment: Thanks Alberto, I was aware of the default language setting, but I'm not prepared to go that route -- I'd rather keep plain text as the default in general.

Comment: For files with extensions the proper route would be add the extension in `Settings > Style configurator`, but it doesn't work for files without extensions (I tried tricks like `.` and `" "` and doesn't work). I'm afraid that the New document route is the only way for that files.

Comment: OK, thanks @Alberto, not ideal but most of my files do have extensions so this should probably be OK. BTW: to be a bit more detailed, it's `Settings > Preferences... > New Document/Default Directory > Default language`